# Misspelling int main(), is this error syntax or runtime?

Tags: java

I'm in an intro to Java class and we're supposed to mark errors as syntax, runtime, or logic.

For this example in a Java program,

```
int main(){
}
```

was misspelled as

```
int man(){
}
```

I thought for sure this was a syntax error because main is misspelled, and the syntax requires it to be main, not man. However, my teacher marked it off and told me it was a runtime because the code is attempted to be run in int main().

I get the idea but I'm still pretty confused. Could anyone help me figure out why misspelling main in int main() wouldn't be a syntax error?

I'll definitely ask my teacher but not going to be in class until next Monday.

Comment: `int man(){}` is a valid method in Java, there's nothing wrong with, even `int main() {}` is valid, but if it was suppose to be the main entry point of the program, then it's wrong for two reasons, one, `main` must be `void` and it must accept a `String[]` argument

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {}` is the actual syntax for the entry point in a `Java` program. What you typed is valid code, but not valid for an entry point.

Comment: The code won't compile. It is **missing a return statement**. So the teacher is wrong, it is a **syntax error** (compile-time error, to be more precise).

Comment: @Zabuza This is what I thought, but he said that because it is compile-time, that is considered a runtime error. Is this true? I thought runtime was after compilation.

Comment: There are two types of problems: Compile-time errors and Run-time exceptions. Compile-time errors happen when you try to compile your code (`javac.exe`, `.java` -> `.class`). Run-time exceptions happen when you already successfully compiled your code and want to run it (`java.exe`). A missing return statement is a **compile-time error**. It is no valid Java, the compiler rejects it and does not understand the code.

Comment: But, it is not because of the *misspelling* and java not finding a `main` method. As explained in my answer, the method (besides the missing return problem), is a completely valid method. And Java does not need any `main` method. Only when you want to run it, you would need one. Because then, you need to tell Java where to start running. This would be at run-time then. But its not really a Java error/exception. More a wrong usage of the Java program. You can't say *"Java, start. Start with `public static void main(String[] args)` in `Foo.class`"* - but then forget the method.

Answer (score 3):

### Missing return statement

Actually, it is a **syntax error** (more precise: *compile-time error*; the code does not compile). But that has nothing to do with `main` being entry point or not.

A method like

```
int man() {

}
```

declares that it returns `int`. But your method does not return anything.

Try compiling the code without `return` statement, you get a compile time error like:

> ```
> Foobar.java:23: error: missing return statement
>   }
>   ^
> 1 error
> ```

It must return an `int`, like:

```
int man() {
    return 42;
}
```

---

### `main` as entry point

The method which is used as entry point for a Java project is called `main` and **must** have the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

(The name of the variable can be changed, *varargs* like `String...` can be used too.)

However, a Java class does not need an entry point. You can compile a class without having any `public static void main(String[] args)` method. You can even compile a whole project without any such method.

Your methods don't have the signature that is required, even the correctly spelled method. It's:

- not `public`,
- not `static`,
- not `void`,
- nor does it accept a `String[]`.

Thus, the compiler accepts it as **ordinary method** and does not care for the name at all.

Answer (score 0):

No reason you can't have a method called `man()` The only thing special about `main()` is that it is an entry point for a program. You can't start your program with `man()`

In your case the fact that it is not `public static void man(String[] args)` would suggest that it isn't a mistake at all, just a method called `man()`

Comment: Actually, in this particular example, `man` couldn't be called like that because it is not `static`. It would not even compile, because it is missing a return statement. I get your point though.

Comment: @Zabuza Good point. I've had my morning coffee now so deleted the lies ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For valid **syntax**, code must have a sequence of tokens (words, symbols, etc.) that can be parsed by the compiler.

These are all valid syntax:

```
int man() {
}

int manly(   ) {}

int fred(){         }

int bob() { ; ; ;; ;; ;;}
```

What makes `int man()` not work but `int main()` work is that the Java runtime knows to look for a method called `main` when it starts the program. If you call it `man`, in is syntactically correct (the compiler can read it), it just won't be found by the runtime when the program starts.

Comment: Actually, a method declaring `int` as return type **must** return an `int`, else it won't compile. So the methods are missing something like `return 42;`.

Comment: @Zabuza So assuming it won't compile, that's considered a runtime error (basically, runtime includes compilation time?)

Comment: No. Explanation in the comments to the question. (Please don't ask the same everywhere)